# Excel 2010 and later -- decimal places

Tags: microsoft-excel

We use a spreadsheet in lab for students to enter data into.  I'd like for Excel to accept the value they enter without doing anything to it -- we are trying to teach them significant figures.  But all the formats except "general" fix the decimal places, and "general" changes 1.0 or 1.00 to just 1 with no decimal places.

Comment: format the cell as text. Excel doesn't store the number of significant digits the user entered

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the entry with a single apostrophe, for example, entering `'1.000` will yield `1.000` with no change to the cell formatting required.